# Indian national holding 'Tier 2 General UK' Visa applying for Schengen Visa from within UK

Tags: uk-visa, schengen, indian-citizens

Can an Indian holding a 'UK Tier 2 General Work Visa' (working in Glasgow, Scotland) apply for a Schengen Travel/Tourism Visa from UK?

Also, is there any stringent requirement of completing certain months in UK before an Indian can apply for Schengen Visa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as a resident of the United Kingdom, you can apply for a Schengen Visa from within the United Kingdom.

Note that different consulates may be responsible based on the area within the United Kingdom that you reside.

According to Schengen rules, applicants have to apply for a visa in the Counslate of the country which can be identified **as the main destination** of their journey.

---

Based on the wording of the [German Mission - Visa Information](https://uk.diplo.de/uk-en/02/visa) site:

> **If you reside in Scotland** or certain parts of northern England you can file your visa application at the VisaMetric Visa Application Centre in Edinburgh from 17 January 2019. [Click here](https://www.visametric.com/uk/germany/en) for more information.

the main condition is that you **reside** there. There is no time constraint stated.

So with your **UK Tier 2 General Work Visa**, that condition should be fulfilled.